# The Camera is not ready yet! Wait for the onInitialized()

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I am trying to implement `react-native-vision-camera` into my React Native app, and it works perfectly as expected on iOS, but on Android it refuses to work properly.
On Android, I am greeted with the following error...

`[session/camera-not-ready] The Camera is not ready yet! Wait for the onInitialized() callback!`

From what I've seen, this error occurs when the  is called before permissions are verified, which is not the case in my app. Consider the following...

```
// Camera Permission State
const [cameraPerm, setCameraPerm] = useState(false)

// Checks Mic and Video Permissions as soon as page loads
useEffect(() => {
  checkPermissions();
}, []);


// Called in a useEffect to gain permissions
const checkPermissions = async () => {
    // Request Permissions on component load
    await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
    await Camera.requestMicrophonePermission();
    await requestPermission()

    const cameraPermission = await Camera.getCameraPermissionStatus();
    setCameraPerm(cameraPermission)
    const microphonePermission = await Camera.getMicrophonePermissionStatus();
};


  // Renders The Camera, if permissed and not done recording
  function renderCameraScreen(){
    // No permissions
    if (device == null) return <View style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}/>;

    // Video Recorded
    if (recorded){
      return(
        <View>
          <Text style={{...FONTS.Title, textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 100}}>
            Video Recorded
          </Text>
        </View>
      )
    }

    if (!cameraPerm){
      return(
        <View>
          <Text style={{...FONTS.Title, textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 100}}>
            Please enable video permissions from your settings to access the camera
          </Text>
        </View>
      )
    }


    return (
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'black', height: maxHeight * 0.70,}}>
        <Camera
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
          device={device}
          isActive={true}
          video={true}
          audio={true}
          ref={camera}
        />
        <View style={{alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: maxHeight * 0.65}}>
          {renderRecordButton()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Considering this, I do not know why I am getting this error. Truthfully, I've also been unable to find any mention of `onInitialized()` in any documentation, so I am unsure how I would even utilize that function, as well as where.

Comment: Did you figure this out? getting the same thing and not sure why

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/789
maybe you need to hide the Camera until your app is authorized to use the Camera.

Comment: I've attempted that, unfortunately. If you look at the `renderCameraScreen()` function, the camera only renders when `cameraPerm` is set to true. This only occurs after `cameraPermissions` is set to true already

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, it is strange.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when using react-native-vision-camera for recording audio and video on Android.

My solution was to use PermissionsAndroid:

Here's my code snippet:

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';

const getAllPermissions = useCallback(async () => {
    PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.RECORD_AUDIO,
    ]).then(result => {
      if (
        result['android.permission.CAMERA'] === 'granted' &&
        result['android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'] === 'granted'
      ) {
        setLoading(devices);
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          'Permission Not Granted',
          'You need to grant this app permission to use the camera to record audio and video',
          [
            {
              text: 'Cancel',
              onPress: () => navigation.pop(),
            },
            {
              text: 'Grant',
              onPress: () => Linking.openSettings(),
            },
          ],
        );
        setLoading(null);
      }
    });
  }, [navigation, devices]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllPermissions();
  }, [getAllPermissions, devices]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add video and audio (optional) to the Camera component

```
<Camera
    style={styles.absoluteFill}
    device={device}
    isActive={true}
    ref={camera}
    video={true}
    audio={true} //optional
/>
```